# Creating a list of years between 2 dates in python

Tags: python

I have 2 dates and want create a list with years between those 2 dates. Somehow struggling to do it in python.

```
date1(2010, 1, 1)
date2(2015, 1, 1)
```

output should look like this

```
years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
```

I have tried the following but cant create a list

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int(date2.year) - int(date1.year)+1):
        yield int(date1.year) + n

start_dt = date(2010, 12, 20)
end_dt = date(2016, 1, 11)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    print(dt)
```

this prints the years but not sure how to put them in a list? also is there a simpler way to create the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two date objects. This would give you the result:

```
from datetime import date

start = date(2010, 1, 1) 
end = date(2015, 1, 1)

year_range = [year for year in range(start.year, end.year +1)]

print(year_range)
```

Answer (score 2):

`daterange` is generator. so just pass it to `list` function.

`years = list(daterange(start_dt, end_dt))`

note, your code could be optimized further

Comment: e.g., look at @MisterNox answer using `range` to iterate over years

Answer (score 1):

Using a `generator` function and not knowing how to collect the yielded items?
Hmm, you can use the following:

```
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int(date2.year) - int(date1.year)+1):
        yield int(date1.year) + n

lst = [item for item in daterange(start_dt, end_dt)]
```

Or use `list(...)` around the generator as in

```
lst = list(daterange(start_dt, end_dt))
```

Either way, you need to "consume" the items from the generator function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you are looking for a pandas function, and I also urge pandas `date_range` function as it's more flexible. You can change the frequency parameter to Day ('D'), Month ('M') and Year ('Y)

```
In [44]: import pandas as pd
    ...:
    ...: [d.strftime('%Y') for d in pd.date_range(start ='1-1-2010', end ='1-1-2015', freq ='Y')]
Out[44]: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `generator`  and it is better to `yield` items into a list like:

```
my_list = list(daterange(start_dt, end_dt))
```

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) you'll find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)
date2 = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int(date2.year) - int(date1.year)+1):
        yield int(date1.year) + n

start_dt = date1
end_dt = date2
dat = []
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    dat.append(dt)
print(dat)
```

**output**

```
[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy as np

for year in np.arange(np.datetime64('2020'),np.datetime64('2025')):
    print(year)

#or a list comprehension
[year for year in np.arange(np.datetime64('2020'),np.datetime64('2025'))]
```